# Shared behavior for mocha tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am baffled that there are so few resources on this topic.

I write a lot of tests for a legacy project. I use Mocha for these, but would be willing to switch to another library if it helps. I'm really frustrated with Mocha's lack of support for shared behavior. We have quite a few tests with great similarities in their setup:

- Setup Inmemory DB for Testcase -> Tear Down DB
- Setup Mocking -> Tear Down Mocking
- ...

I am used to JUnit where this would have been extracted into a `Rule` or an `Extension`. [Mocha claims there is no concept of shared behaviors](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Shared-Behaviours). Now I wonder how everyone else handles this? Does everyone write utilities and call the predefined before and after hooks in each suite? Or are there third-party plugins or nasty hacks to enable shared behaviors?

*Edit 1:*

To clarify: What I want is some way to have reusable hooks without having to repeat myself over and over again.

So instead of writing something like this in 20 testcases:

```
  describe('some test using a specific environment', function(){
    let envBackup;
    let db;

    before(async function() {
      db = setupDatabase({name: 'test-db-123'});
      envBackup= saveAllEnvironemtVariables();
    });

    after(async function() {
      restoreAllEnvironmentVariables(envBackup);
      deleteDb(db);
    });

    beforeEach(async function() {
      setupTextFixture({foo: 'bar', cow: 'moo'});
      resetDb(db);
    });
  });
```

I'd prefer having a less verbose way of writing it, more like this:

```
  describe('some test using a specific environment', function(){
    runWithDatabase(this, {name: 'test-db-123'});
    runWithFixedEnvironment(this, {foo: 'bar', cow: 'moo'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for what mocha calls hooks. https://mochajs.org/#hooks These let you do common setup/teardown for each test. The beforeEach/afterEach hook will run before and after every test. In here you can call your function to set up your in memory DB or mocking. Alternatively if you want to just run the setup/teardown once per test suite then you can use the before/after hooks. If you have setup/teardown that you want to run only at the start and end of your entire set of test suites then you probably want to use global fixtures or root hooks. https://mochajs.org/#test-fixture-decision-tree-wizard-thing

The most common approach would be something like this:

```
describe('My test suite', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // Set up in memory DB
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Tear down DB
    });

    it('A test that uses the in memory DB', () => {
        // Do something with the DB
    });
});
```

If you're running test suites in parallel you'll also need to consider that multiple in memory DB's may be up at the same time and you probably want them to use different ports so that the test suites don't conflict with each other.

Comment: Hi there and thank you very much for your answer. I'm aware of hooks. I want reusable sets of hooks. I'll edit my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking way to complex for a long time, I finally came up with a simple solution which solves my problem in a beautifully trivial way. I did not know you can actually call the mocha hooks in nested functions.

So I created a set of setup-Methods which create hooks for each Setup-Step necessary.

For example, my setup for a test-database now looks like this:

```
export function withPartialModel(...models: ModelDefinition[]): TestContextSetup<{ db: Database }> {
  return (suiteContext, nestedSetup) => {
    let db: Database ;
    before(function () {
      db= createDbFor(...models);
      suiteContext.db= db;
    });

    beforeEach(async function () {
      await db.createSchema();
    });

    applySetup(nestedSetup, suiteContext);

    afterEach(async function () {
      await db.drop();
    });

    return suiteContext;
  };
}
```

The test itself now looks like this

```
describe('My fancy test', function(){
  const context = enhanceTest(
      withPartialModel(TestEntity), 
      withFixture({MY_ENV_VAR_FOR_THIS_TEST:'FAlSE'}));
});
```